# dynamic select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have posts that gets filtered based on location, category and tags, so I have 3 select_tag that chooses the filtering. The items in the select_tag are of this form name (num) where num is the number of posts that satisfy the filter. As you can see if I have Boston (20) for location and Computer (10) for category, there's no way to tell how many results I will come up with if I specify both Boston and Computer. I was wondering if after I choose Boston (20), the select_tags will update itself so Computer (10) might become Computer (5) and so on.

Comment: Take a look at this Railscast [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an ajax call to get either the data in the new select tag via JSON or a completely new select tag rendered as HTML that you can use to replace your current select tag.  If you are using jQuery you can probably do something like this:

```
$('.category').load('/categories/select?location='+$('.location').value());
```

Where select would be an action on CategoriesController that would generate the HTML for the new category select tag.